# How to run GLM on a data.frame with different column names than that on which the GLM was trained?

Tags: r, glm, names

I have a legacy GLM model which was trained on weather data many years ago. The modern weather data has different column names from the original data.

CONTEXT: I am predicting events based on weather.

COLUMN NAME CHANGE EXAMPLE: The newer data.frame has different column names.  In the original data.frame (on which the GLM was fit/trained) there was a column called "rainfall", and in the new data.frame it is called "RAIN_M40".

QUESTION: Is there a way to use the existing GLM without changing the name of the new column ("RAIN_M40") to the older name ("rainfall")"?

```
# 1) Generate some random example data

original_data <- data.frame(events = rbinom(500, 1, 0.1), rainfall = runif(500))

current_data <- data.frame(RAIN_M40 = original_data$rainfall)



# 2) build the model on the original data

model_name <- glm(events ~ rainfall, family = poisson(), data = original_data)



# 3) predict the model using the original data (this works fine)


original_data$predicted_events <- predict((model_name), newdata = original_data, type = "response")



# 3) predict the model using the current data.frame  (does not work)

current_data$predicted_events <- predict((model_name), newdata = current_data, type = "response")

# returns the following error as column "rainfall" is now called "RAIN_M40": Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'rainfall' not found








## CURRENT WORK AROUND ---------------


# 4) duplicating the column, giving it the new name so the model runs (but I don't want to have to do this!)

current_data$rainfall <- current_data$RAIN_M40




# 5) predict the model using the current data.frame  (this works fine, but the data is twice as big)

current_data$predicted_events <- predict((model_name), newdata = current_data, type = "response")


# ===================
 # My brother's solution:

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

fr1 <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 1:3)
fr2 <- data.table(X = 1:3, Y = 1:3)

fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = fr1)

predict(fit, newdata = within(fr2, x <- X))

predict(fit, newdata = copy(fr2) %>% setnames("X", "x"))

# =========================
```

CURRENT SOLUTION: My current workaround is to replicate the columns, so to include one for each name, but this is ugly, and as the data is very large, inefficient. The model is not allowed to be changed / retrained for reporting reasons.

I would appreciate any suggestions you may have. Many thanks indeed.

EDIT: a number of approaches to solving this are provided at the end, thanks to my brother. Some use data.table. I've not yet tested them for speed etc, but they are here as a reference for others with these issues!

Comment: Before you do any hacks concerning the column names you MUST make sure that the only change is the column names and not the column values. If the column values are different your predictions will be extremely affected. Maybe in some columns the variable scale has changed. Eg: values like 400, 450, 500 became 4, 4.5, 5.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, code added.

Comment: AntonioK - thank you - yes the data values are the same. Thanks

Comment: not sure how can this be avoided without copying the column as model is already trained with `rainfall` column. However, you can delete `RAIN_M40` column after the copy so you do not have duplicate column. `cuurent_data$RAIN_M40 <- NULL`

Comment: Thank Ronak - yes, that is possible, but other models which also run on this data use the current names (e.g. RAIN_M40) - so this is why I was hoping to find an alias function or something!

Comment: This is the answer my brother has provided, which described two ways of doing this: `library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

fr1 <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 1:3)
fr2 <- data.table(X = 1:3, Y = 1:3)

fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = fr1)

predict(fit, newdata = within(fr2, x <- X))

predict(fit, newdata = copy(fr2) %>% setnames("X", "x")) `